# Is there a dpkg argument to warn about incomptibilities/broken dependencies?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, package-management, dpkg, deb

A command like `dpkg -i *.deb` will install all deb files in a folder without warning of incompatibilities and such.

Can this command be changed so that installation of broken packages is avoided, warning displayed, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> incompatibilities and such

What do you mean by that?

Before installing, `dpkg` first checks if all dependencies of the .deb package(s) to be installed are satisfied. If the `dpkg` database is inconsistent, a message is printed.

Comment: I thought it does not,  broken dependencies may appear, but I guess that is a different issue.